# Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php

Following is the code in which i tried to submit the form details to the mysql database in my cpanel of godaddy.

```
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $phnoErr= "";
    $name = $area = $address = $phno = $email = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

      if (!$con)
      {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

      mysql_select_db("fecustomer", $con);


        $name = $_POST["name"];

        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
          $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }

         $area = $_POST["area"];
          $address = $_POST["address"];

        $phno = $_POST["phno"];

        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9 ]*$/",$phno)) {
          $phnoErr = "Only 10 digits allowed"; 
        }


          $email = $_POST["email"];

        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }





    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    }





      $query = "
      INSERT INTO `fecustomer`.`details` (`name`, `area`, `address`, `email`,
            `phno`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$name','$area','address','phno'
            '$email');";

      mysql_query($query);

      echo "<p>Thank you for your Comment!</p>";

      mysql_close($con);
    }
    else
    echo "dint insert";

    ?>
```

I have registered my domain and hosting in godaddy.i wanted to use the database in that itself.Have i udes the mysql of local wamp server.Are both different?what should i do.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, your mysql username and password is not correct and so, can not connect.

Your local database credentials and Godaddy credentials surely varies.

You will have to create a database admin first, then create a database. You will have to use these credentials in your code to fix the issue.

Go to `MySQL Databases` section on your panel. Then `Create A New Database`and `Add An User`.

More details: https://in.godaddy.com/help/create-mysql-databases-16016

Use the credentials here:

`$con = mysql_connect("localhost","your_username","your_password");`